# The code that worked for cy.route with bit refactor doesn't work for cy.intercept

Tags: javascript, cypress

The below refactored code doesn't wait for the API request. Value1 is the value keyed in by me in the application in a listbox and I have to wait for the API request that is sent to fetch the list of matching values after I keyed in the value.

API Request with cy.route that worked
cy.route("GET", `/api/v2/lookup/companies?keyword=${Value1}`).as(  "getValue1");

API Request with cy.intercept :
cy.intercept({
method: "GET",
url: `/api/v2/lookup/companies?keyword=${Value1}`,
}).as("getValue1");

Comment: You seem to have changed the URL as well, is that correct? I'd expect a *refactor* not to alter which request you were trying to mock out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, those are two different request urls. the first api request is not found so I dont know whether the second api request will be found..So I gave here to find out what would be the correct way to write.

Comment: That's a slightly confusing way to present it; I'd suggest focussing on showing a *single* request, before (`cy.route`) and after (`cy.intercept`), with a bit of context (i.e. [mre] of a test).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, sorry about the confusion. Please see my updated question.